# Number of ways to insert elements into an AVL tree such that there are no rotations

Tags: data-structures, combinatorics, avl-trees

How many ways can we insert elements { 1, 2, 3, .... 7 } to make an AVL tree so that it does not have any rotation?

I broke it down into 2 cases:

Case 1: height of tree = 2, (a complete binary tree) only 1 structure possible.

case 2: height of tree = 3, there will be 16 structures possible.
there will not be an AVL tree of height 4 as AVL trees of height 4 require at least 12 nodes.

Now the problem is, I have the possible structures but I need to find the order of insertion into this structure(it is possible but I feel a better approach should be there)

Comment: What do you mean by "the tree does not have any rotation"? Do you mean that no rotation is needed considering a given insertion order?

Comment: yes, when the elements are inserted into the tree according to the sequence no rotation is needed

Comment: @ArunMadhav, your title suggests that you are looking for the number of ways of inserting without rotation but in the content you are asking how to insert without rotation

Comment: @Russel In my approach as I have the structures, I need to find the sequence of insertion for each structure but for 17 structures will be time-consuming, I want to know if there is a smart way to count the sequence of insertions into the structure or another approach to solve the problem